# Trouble with thumb placement when practicing arpeggios on a piano

Tags: piano, practice, fingering, arpeggios

I'm just now learning the correct fingering for when practicing scales and arpeggios. Scales are going quite well, but when I practice arpeggios, I seem to have a lot of trouble with my thumb placement. More specifically when I move to the second octave.

For example with a C major arpeggio, I press C > E > G with my thumb, indexfinger and middlefinger. But then I need to move my thumb all the way across to the next C underneath my hand. My wrist feels very uncomfortable when I do this. I also often press the C key very hard because I need to move my thumb very quickly in order to make it in time. Even if I try to start out slowly. I try to move my elbow to the right when doing this movement and it helps slightly, but it still feels uncomfortable in my wrist.

Does anyone have any tips on this issue that might help? Or is it really just practicing slowly until it gets better? The uncomfortable feeling makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arm places the thumb.  Using just your arm and gravity - not your thumb's abductor, play your thumb down on C, then from the arm, lift up the arm and hand and leading with your elbow play the octave higher C.

Regarding your wrist pain, a lot of times when a pianist crosses the thumb under the palm, they anticipate the next finger position and twist the wrist.  This is called ulnar deviation going up and radial deviation going down.  Eventually, too much twisting can cause problems.  It will surely make you play unevenly and make your hands feel weak.  Get your playing into your arms before you start using your fingers (forearm muscles).

To help propel your arm, and thumb, use your pronator and supinator muscles to rotate the forearm.  They are located around your elbow.  With your arm in front of your chest, rotate left and right very fast.  Notice how fast you can move your thumb and pinky and notice that they don't fatigue at all.   Those are the muscles you should use to play the thumb.

Also, because of rotation, remember that every motion has an equal and opposite motion.  Using your pronator to play the first note with your thumb actually should start with supination.  The rotation in the opposite direction gives the finger power and speed without using any muscles that actually move the fingers.

Throw something. Notice that you first swing in the opposite direction you are throwing the object. You need that in your piano playing but up, down, in, out, left and right.  Try to play with a "still and quiet  hand" and you will indeed create tension.  Play from the arm and the hand will be still and quiet.

Answer (score 8):

It's not so much making your thumb go underneath the fingers/palm as moving your whole hand. As soon as you've played the first C, the whole hand should have started to move right. By the time your middle finger hits the G, your thumb should be under that part of your palm. Whole hand then continues gently right, putting the thumb onto the next C.

The thump on that C is because you play the first three notes, then start to move your whole hand. Imagine instead your hand gently flowing to the right as each note gets played. As you then hit the second C, it stretches out so the other fingers are in line with the last three notes.

It all needs to be done in real slomo to start with, listening for even play on every note. Gradually, over a week, speed up, and you'll find it'll flow like it should.

When you come to play chromatics, the same trick works - concentrate on keeping the whole hand moving, with the wrist at the same height all the time.

Comment: Do I let go of the G key with my middlefinger before I press the second C with my thumb? Or should I simultaneously let go of G and press C? Because if I gently move my hand to the right, I will inevitably have to let go of G or do an awkward stretch with my hand.

Comment: the first point your mentioning is exactly what I would have given as advice too. I had no problems going up to the 3rd and the 5th but then I had the same problem as the OP. Last summer my grandchild started with piano lessons and he was playing the Chopin, Op. 10,1 in a very slow speed. I started to compete with him and looking for other analysis than mine I dropped to this SE site. And there have been already  similar questions and answers already given to this subject.

Comment: That's something you'll have to work out, dependent somewhat on how long your fingers are and how pliable your hand is. Trying to play legato, as arps are often played, requires the notes to flow into each other, not bleed into each other.

Comment: @Albrecht Hügli I always do some research before asking a question on here, but I was unable to find information on my specific situation. That is not to say that there isn't any. Perhaps my search term was incorrect or I used the wrong terminology.

Comment: @Tim Alright, thanks for the answers. My fingers aren't short but they're not the longest either. I think with some practice I should be able let the notes flow into each other. Or at least I hope so. But my main priority now is practicing slowly and making sure there's no strain in my wrist.

Comment: Tipsi, this was not a critic. My comment was not finished, as I looked up the mailbox the comment has been posted. What I was going to say is that you'll find further advice when you look up here how to get speed in Chopin op. 10;1. I have found pdf of Cortot and Godowsky in IMLP and was surprised that they were  not mentioned in the answers to this questions.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli - it's always possible to re-write a comment, add what's needed, post it, then delete the original comment.

Comment: It's way too soon to decide it's the preferred answer! There may well be other far better ones in the pipeline from people who have to do other things, like work for a living!

Comment: yes, Tim, I know. Thank you.  But only 5 minutes. As you can see, I was in the same moment going to the question about reading  the bass clef and while commenting there this one here was closed. no problem! (as I write so slowly ;)

Comment: @Tim you're right. I did it again. I'm used to stackoverflow for programming questions. Usually when you get a correct answer there, you'll accept that answer if it solves your problem. But music is very different, there are always different perspectives to seeing things and no answer is the be-all, end-all answer like it often is with programming.

Comment: Check out an organ arrangement of *Tico Tico No Fuba*

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are using this fingering...

[image]

Obviously, you are having trouble with the transition from finger 3 to 1, the `G4` to `C5` move.

First thought: if playing the `C` major chord is considered easy, because so much beginner stuff is in `C` major, reconsider that all white key passages can be *harder* than a mix of black and white keys.

Try playing this arpeggio on `B` major. It should fit the right hand much more naturally. You can use this as a sort of transitional pattern to get the feel of passing the thumb under in an easier position. Compare it to the movement on `C` major.

Try playing the arpeggio *descending* as well as ascending. It shifts the which finger is last in the first position and first in the next. In other words, when ascending finger 3 is sort of 'holding' the first position, then finger 1 is in movement to get to the next position. When descending the finger roles are reversed, finger 1 is holding the first postion, finger 3 is in movement. It's a subtle difference, but it might help you get comfortable with the crossing under.

Also, you might try playing the full octave like this `C4, E4, G4, C5` with fingering 1, 2, 3, 5. Then to change position you make a *repeated note* fingering on `C5` using fingers 5, 1. Obviously, this doesn't *directly* practice passing the thumb under, but it will help with two things: help finger 1 spatially find `C5`, and contracting the hand to bring fingers 1 and 5 together. Both of those should help develop your hand and benefit crossing under.

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with Tim!

To get faster you have to move the whole hand (first looking and then  trying to play "blind" (closed eyes):

1. try to catch/touch  the 3 black keys over all octaves from down to up by your  1. finger on f# (right hand)
2. the same catch/touch with closed  the 2 black keys  starting with C#
3. when you have the orientation for finding the black keys try to find with closed eyes the key of C playing with your thumb and touching c# and d# with fingers 2 and 3 across all the octaves.
4. start to get more speed by playing the full triad (not arpeggio but the whole chord)
5. the same as ex. 4. but playing c-e-g-c by 1-2-3-5

look up for Chopin op. 10,1 in IMSLP, (also Godowsky and Cortot)
and look the advises in this SE

searching for Chopin etudes, CORTOT  and Godowsky.